# Radius-Variable Screwing, possibly involving nodes

Tags: python, modifiers, geometry, geometry-nodes, screw-modifier

a novice here looking to be ambitious (and presently failing).

I'm trying to take a polygon plane (*approximately* circular and with radius = R) and screw modifier it with an R that reduces in size with z-position, such as described in the attached media, such that the eventual screw mimics a circle.

[image]

Given that a similar solution is presented in method 2 [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74958/screw-modifier-with-varying-offset), I suspect the solution will involve either Geometry or Animation nodes, but as a 3D modelling novice, I have absolutely **no** idea how to do nodes, and I'm not even sure that Blender can do what I'm asking. I also suspect that a python script would be involved.

Advice, pointers, suggestions, and demonstrations from the advanced blender community would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Even links to appropriate nodes & python youtube tutorials would be great - my problem as a novice is in part not knowing what to search for...

Comment: Hi, welcome to BSE! We're a welcoming community, however we're driven by a very specific ruleset: [Tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour). Please make the title of the question specific, e.g. "Use a screw modifier on a circle to get a sphere", also please put some effort into the question: a scan of a sketch is absolutely fine, but you should write down the description in a text form that will be searchable. Also show what you have tried already as a proof of doing your homework, cheers!

Comment: ... or is [this](https://imgur.com/CPvqqDf) the sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

A screw modifier is probably not the way to go, or perhaps I don't understand your question... The question linked by you indeed produces a screw. The sketch you provide doesn't resemble a screw.

So let me try to take advantage of Cunningham's Law and post a first answer:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that OP may wish to rotate each plane to form the screw, something like this?

[image]

So a node layout something like this?

[image]